# Paramiko SSH - "systemctl status tomcat" returns code 3 when Tomcat is stopped

Tags: python, tomcat, ssh, debian, paramiko

Take the following Python code as an example when connecting via SSH into a Debian server:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('sudo systemctl stop tomcat')
    if stdout.channel.recv_exit_status() != 0:
        for line in iter(stderr.readline, ""):
                print(line)

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('sudo systemctl status tomcat')
if stdout.channel.recv_exit_status() != 0:
        for line in iter(stderr.readline, ""):
                print(line)
```

stdout.channel.recv_exit_status() for the second SSH commands returns 3 - whatever that means.
Is it the SSH return code? The Debian host return code? The documentation suggests the latter: http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/channel.html ("the exit code (as an int) of the process on the server.")

Rather interestingly, if I **start** Tomcat with the same command and then call the status of the service, it returns 0, thus leading me to believe I for whatever reason can't get the status of Tomcat when it's stopped. Yet if I SSH into the server myself, the status command works regardless if Tomcat is started or not.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`systemctl status tomcat` will return 3 as an exit code if tomcat is stopped, so this behaviour is normal.

`systemctl status <service>`'s exit code will indicate the status of the requested service, rather than the success of the actual check.

If you run `systemctl status tomcat` when tomcat is stopped, then run `echo $?`, you'll see that the exit code is 3. If tomcat is running, it should return 0.

`systemctl status` follows LSB spec in this regard -- the full list of possible exit codes is here: https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/iniscrptact.html.

Comment: Thanks, but why when the same command returns 0 when it's started? I'm only interested in whether the command to acquire the status succeeds - I don't particularly care if the service has started or stopped (that comes later).

Comment: `systemctl status`'s exit code will indicate the status of the requested service, rather than the success in the actual check.

If you run `systemctl status tomcat` when tomcat is stopped, then run `echo $?`, you'll see that the exit code is 3. If tomcat is running, it should return 1. 

`systemctl status` follows LSB spec in this regard -- the full list of possible exit codes is here: https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/iniscrptact.html.

I've added the above to my answer, since I wasn't very clear about this!